# Set up MapServer WMS from tile files

Tags: gdal, wms, mapserver, tiles

I'm totally new to MapServer and I've been banging my head trying to figure out how to mount a WMS server that will seed images of a small geographical area to a OpenLayers HTML page.

I already installed Mapserver on windows (MS4W) and "mapserver -v" shows: **'SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER'** so that's done.

Then I used **JTileDownloader** to get the tiles from the area I'm interested in. I ended up with folders "13" and "14" (guess that the zoom level) full of *.png file inside the folder c:\TMP\MyZone

The next steps seems to be to create an index file from the tiles with gdaltindex witch I manage to install, but I have no idea how to use.

While on the **c:\TMP\MyZone** folder I tried:

> gdaltindex PR1314.shp
>
> gdaltindex PR1314.shp *.png
>
> gdaltindex PR1314.shp 13\*.png

But none of them worked so I don't know what to do, I read a lot articles in MapServer wiki how-to's, but the amount of info is overwhelming and I don't understand half of what I'm reading.

So to recap, I just need a WMS that will seed the tiles I already downloaded. What should I do next?

Comment: either this is a really stupid question, or the wrong place to ask it.

Comment: A bit late, but see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155053/how-do-i-create-a-mapserver-config-file-for-tiles-downloaded-from-wmts-service/156163#156163 . Also, using MapProxy is a better option imho.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use MapProx (http://mapproxy.org/) which does what you need.

Alternatively, see this answer which develops your procedure a bit further:  [How do I create a mapserver config file for tiles downloaded from WMTS service?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155053/how-do-i-create-a-mapserver-config-file-for-tiles-downloaded-from-wmts-service/156163#156163) .